# Windows: How to append text at a particular location in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to append the password to a file(I have password stored in another file). So basically I will be looping thru the file and checking for the field SYS_PASSWD= 
I need to append the password to this field. Is there a way to do it using dos script? What option should I use? An example will help.
Thanks

Comment: I'm using a batch script which I will be calling inside python.

Comment: Then you are not using "DOS", you are using Windows (there is no Python for DOS)

Comment: Yes on windows... batch script is what I'm writing..

Comment: Is this keystring unique in the file? Does it occur as the sole contents of the line on which it occurs? Is it indented or suffixed by spaces or other whitespace?

Comment: Yes its unique in the file and is not prefixed/suffixed with spaces or other whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Get password from file "q24730439.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q24730439.txt) DO SET "syspasswd=%%a"

:: insert password into appropriate place in "24730439q.txt"
:: creating newfile.txt
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (24730439q.txt) DO (
  IF "%%a"=="SYS_PASSWD=" (ECHO %%a%syspasswd%) ELSE (ECHO %%a)
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

This procedure appends the password in `q24730439.txt` to the line `SYS_PASSWD=` in `24730439q.txt`, producing `newfile.txt`

---

`"delims="` turns off delimiters by setting the delimter character set to empty. Consequently, the entire line is assigned to the metavariable `%%a`

You stated simply `have password stored in another file` - the setting of the variable in the manner indicated will read the password from the file `q24730439.txt`. You have given no other indication of how to derive the password, and I can't read your mind.

It is normal practice to create new files so the solution can be debugged. In the same way, a `delete` or `rename` would normally simply be `echo`ed rather than being executed so that no damage can occur if the developer 's system and OP's system differ. All that needs to be done would be to remove the `echo` to activate the rename/deletion - but that step is last, after the verification that the correct instruction sequence will be generated.

In your case, creating a new file allows

```
fc newfile.txt 24730439q.txt
```

to be executed to see the differences.

Once you've verified that the results are correct, a simple

```
move /y newfile.txt 24730439q.txt >nul 2>nul
```

overwrites the old file with the new. This command can be inserted before the `goto :eof` - but only after correct operation of the procedure has been verified.

Comment: What does "delims=" mean? No spaces?

Comment: Also I did not understand your first part get password from file. The password file has just password in it. The 2nd file is a property file to which I'm passing the password.

Comment: Magoo's solution is the optimal way to perform this operation in any manner. :)

Comment: That solution partially worked but I dont want to created a new file I want it to append it to 24730439q.txt(the property file)